# How can I match a control sequence using \regex_match?

Tags: l3regex

How can I match a control sequence using `\regex_match`?
This code

```
\newcommand{\iw}[1]{\immediate\write16{#1}}

\iw{1 should be true}
\regex_match:nnTF {May} {May} {\iw{TRUE}} {\iw{FALSE}}

\newcommand{\z}{May}
\iw{2 should be true}
\regex_match:nnTF {May} {\z} {\iw{TRUE}} {\iw{FALSE}}
```

prints

```
1shouldbetrue
TRUE
2shouldbetrue
FALSE
```

and I want it to print

```
1shouldbetrue
TRUE
2shouldbetrue
TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very familiar with `l3regex` so can't comment on whether there is a better/more appropriate way of doing what you want (aside from the fact it doesn't appear that regular expressions are required).  However, I believe the problem with the above code is that the macro

```
\regex_match:nnTF {May} {\z} {\iw{TRUE}} {\iw{FALSE}}
```

is comparing `May` to `\z`, rather than comparing `May` to the content of `\z` as you intend.  This is because the `nn` part of the argument specifier says to do nothing with the arguments.  What you want is to replace the second argument `\z` with its replacement text before doing the comparison.  This can be accomplished by using a `V` argument type.

Again, without familiarity with `l3regex` I can't say whether there is a better "built in" way of doing this, but one option is to use `expl3` to generate a variant with the correct argument type.  I did that below with

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF {nV}
```

after which you can call

```
\regex_match:nVTF {May} \z {\iw{TRUE}} {\iw{FALSE}}
```

when `\z` is replaced with its value before the comparison is made.

---

In the specific example of your above code, the same can be accomplished without regular expressions using one of

```
\tl_if_in:NnTF \z {May} {\iw{TRUE}} {\iw{FALSE}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_in:nnTF {nV}
\tl_if_in:NnTF {May} \z {\iw{TRUE}} {\iw{FALSE}}
```

or,

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF {nV}
\tl_if_eq:nVTF {May} \z {\iw{TRUE}} {\iw{FALSE}}
```

depending on your intentions.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\iw}[1]{\immediate\write16{#1}}

\iw{1 should be true}
\regex_match:nnTF {May} {May} {\iw{TRUE}} {\iw{FALSE}}

\newcommand{\z}{May}
\iw{2 should be true}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF {nV}
\regex_match:nVTF {May} \z {\iw{TRUE}} {\iw{FALSE}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `l3regex` *never* expands macros; it just compare token lists independently from their meaning. One can specify control sequence names in a regex with `\c{foo}` to mean `\foo`; however, even if `\foo` and `\baz` are “`\ifx`-equivalent”, the regex `\c{foo}` will *not* match `\c{baz}`. Your method of generating a variant is what's needed in this very particular situation.